# Brazilian Portuguese diphthongs and hiatuses

Tags: ortografia, pronúncia

I would like to know the list of diphthongs and hiatuses in Brazilian Portuguese. Because I need the correct syllable division.

Comment: Niconii, with all due respect, to know that doesn't help you divide syllables. It would be better to learn about the orthography, mainly about diacritics, since there's rarely more than one possible syllabic division if you use the orthography. By the why, I am presuming you're not talking about poetic syllables.

Comment: What I mean is the list of diphthongs (like ai, ae, oi, ãe, ão, õe) and hiatuses.

Comment: Niconii, I know, that was just a comment. There's a list of diphthongs in en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portuguese_phonology#Oral_diphthongs, but I don't know where to find a list of hiatuses in Portuguese, but I am pretty sure someone else in this site will know.

Comment: Niconii, I'm with @Schilive, bacause the same sequence of letters may or may not be a diphthong. For instance (a dot indicates syllable separation), *c**oi**.sa* (diphthong *oi*), but *mo.i.nho*; *c**ui**.do* (diphthong *ui*), but *ru.í.do* (here, as in most cases, graphical accents help); but even in *moinho* and *ruído* there's no hiatus, because we fill it with a semiconsonant (we tend to "fill" hiatuses in this way); but this is about pronunciation; presumably you're just interested in writing, and by hiatus you simply mean two adjacent vowels that are not diphthongs, right?

Comment: @Jacinto Yes, it is right. I would like to know the kind of hiatuses and diphthongs.

Comment: I think that knowing what diphthongs exist _will_ help a lot as a starting point. But then there's a long path ahead because there's a lot more to it, like Jacinto explains very well. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As spelling is concerned, diphthongs and hiatuses are the same in Brazil and Portugal; there are some differences in pronunciation. I’ll focus on spelling and the “official” syllable division, which determines where you can hyphenate a word, but include some notes on pronunciation and examples with audio links where you can hear native speakers pronouncing the words; I indicate syllable division with a dot.

### Diphthongs

**Falling oral diphthongs** ― vowel + i or vowel + u:

> *ai*      [p**ai**](https://forvo.com/word/pai/#pt)   [r**ai**.va](https://forvo.com/word/raiva/#pt)
> *ei*      [i.d**ei**.a](https://forvo.com/word/ideia/#pt)   [a.n**éi**s](https://forvo.com/word/an%C3%A9is/#pt)           /ɛj/ open *e*
>          [l**ei**](https://forvo.com/word/lei/#pt)   [j**ei**.to](https://forvo.com/word/jeito/#pt)                    /ej/ closed *e*; for many speakers in Portugal, /ɐj/ closed *a*
> *oi*      [cons.tr**ói**](https://forvo.com/word/constr%C3%B3i/#pt)   [j**oi**.a](https://forvo.com/word/joia/#pt)          /ɔi/ open *o*
>          [b**oi**](https://forvo.com/word/boi/#pt)   [d**oi**da](https://forvo.com/word/doida/#pt)                  /oj/ closed *o*
> *ui*      [c**ui**.dar](https://forvo.com/word/cuidar/#pt)   [R**ui**](https://forvo.com/word/rui/#pt)
>
> *au*      [ca.c**au**](https://forvo.com/word/cacau/#pt)   [**au**.tor](https://forvo.com/word/autor/#pt)
> *eu*      [c**éu**](https://forvo.com/word/c%C3%A9u/#pt)   [cha.p**éu**s](https://forvo.com/search/chap%C3%A9u/)         /ɛw/ open *e*
>           [m**eu**](https://forvo.com/word/meu/#pt)   [**Eu**.ro.pa](https://forvo.com/word/europa/#pt)            /ew/ closed *e*
> *iu*       [r**iu**](https://forvo.com/word/riu/#pt)   [tra.**iu**](https://forvo.com/word/traiu/#pt)      
> *ou*      [s**ou**](https://forvo.com/word/sou/#pt)   [M**ou**.ri.nho](https://forvo.com/word/jos%C3%A9_mourinho/#pt)       most Portuguese and some Brazilian reduce this to  /o/ closed *o*

**Falling nasal diphthongs**

> *ão*      [p**ão**](https://forvo.com/word/p%C3%A3o/#pt)   [a.vi.**ão**](https://forvo.com/word/avi%C3%A3o/#pt)
> *ãe*      [m**ãe**](https://forvo.com/word/m%C3%A3e/#pt)   [p**ãe**s](https://forvo.com/word/p%C3%A3es/#pt)
> *õe*      [p**õe**](https://forvo.com/word/p%C3%B5e/#pt)   [Ca.m**õe**s](https://forvo.com/word/cam%C3%B5es/#pt)
> *ui*       [m**ui**.to](https://forvo.com/word/muito/#pt)           /ũj/, it is nasal even though there is no graphical indication

**Phonetic diphthongs you wouldn't guess from spelling**. There are nasal phonetic diphthongs in end-of-word *-em* as in [v**em**](https://forvo.com/search/vem/) or [tam.b**ém**](https://forvo.com/word/tamb%C3%A9m/#pt), pronounced [ẽj]; [ɐ̃j], rhymes with *mãe*, in central and southern Portugal. End-of-word *-êm*, as in [t**êm**](https://forvo.com/word/t%C3%AAm/#pt), is [ẽj] in Brazil, and the double diphthong [ɐ̃jɐ̃j] in much of Portugal. End-of-word *-am* is as *ão*, [ɐ̃w], as in [fo.r**am**](https://forvo.com/word/foram/#pt). In Brasil too end-of-syllable *l* is usually vocalized into [w], creating phonetic diphthongs. Hence the *al* in [*Na.t**al***](https://forvo.com/word/natal/#pt) is pronounced /aw/; the *ol* is [*s**ol***](https://forvo.com/word/natal/#pt) as /ɔw/ ― this diphthong /ɔw/, with an open *o*, does not exist otherwise in Portuguese language (*ou* is always /ow/, closed *o*, or reduced to the monophthong /o/).

**Rising diphthongs** starting with *u* occur after *g* and *q* in words like [*á.g**ua***](https://forvo.com/word/%C3%A1gua/#pt), [*q**ua**.tro*](https://forvo.com/word/quatro/#pt), [*a.g**uen**.tar*](https://forvo.com/word/aguentar/#pt), [*tran.q**ui**.lo*](https://forvo.com/word/tranquilo/#pt), [ar.g**ui**r*](https://forvo.com/word/arguir/#pt), [*q**uó**.rum*](https://forvo.com/word/qu%C3%B3rum/#pt). This is not universal though: the *u* in these *ui* and *ue* is silent in many such words, like [*es.qui.lo*](https://forvo.com/word/esquilo/#pt), [ma.la.gue.ta](https://forvo.com/word/malagueta/#pt), etc.  If you do not know, the only way is to look up a dictionary that shows pronunciation, like [Michaelis](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/arguir/)  (Brazilian standard), [Priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/arguir) (you can select Brazilian or European standard) or [Infopédia](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/arguir) (European standard).

### Hiatuses

There are true hiatuses in Portuguese such as *aé* in ***a.é**.ria* and *ií* in *fr**i.í**.ssimo*, that is two adjacent vowels that belong to different syllables (dot shows syllable separation), and are therefore pronounced separately, not as a diphthong. But then there lots of “official” hiatuses that are undone in standard pronunciation. This can vary a great deal between Brazil and Portugal, and within Brazil itself. For instance, *leão* has officially two syllables and a hiatus, *l**e.ão***, but the Portuguese and many Brazilians turn the *e* into the semivowel [j] and pronounce the word as the triphthong /ljɐ̃w /; in Portugal this is the standard pronunciation, as shown in dictionaries such as [Infopédia](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/le%C3%A3o). The same goes for [*pra.t**e.a**.do*](https://forvo.com/word/prateado/#pt), where *e.a* is “officially” a hiatus, but is pronounced as the rising diphthong /ja/; in [Forvo](https://forvo.com/word/prateado/#pt) one Brazilian pronounces it as a diphthong, another as a hiatus. Now this is pronunciation. Official orthography has them as hiatuses, which means that you can hyphenate the word there at the end of a line (*le- ão*, *prate- ado*, although some such hyphenations are discouraged anyway).

So I’ll now follow the spelling and show official hiatuses regardless of whether they are pronounced as hiatuses or not. And I’m pleased to announce that off all possible twenty-five pairs of vowel letters, twenty-four can be found as hiatuses in words recorded in dictionaries, and the twenty-fifith can be found in a word not recorded in dictionaries. One pair, say *i.a*, can appear in several different hiatuses, because the hiatus may be formed of just the two letters (*p**i.a**no*), or each of the letters may be part of a diphthong (*p**i.ão***, *b**oi.a***, *b**oi.ão***), the second vowel may be nasal (*cr**i.an**ça*), and so on. I’ll group the examples according to the two letters on either side of the hiatus, and highlight in boldface all the letters that belong with them, as in the examples above.

> *a.a*      [b**a.a**.miano](https://forvo.com/word/baamiano/#pt)   [A.br**a.ão**](https://forvo.com/word/abra%C3%A3o/#pt)
> *a.e*      [**a.e**.ro.por.to](https://forvo.com/word/aeroporto/#pt)
> *a.i*       [p**a.í**.s](https://forvo.com/word/pa%C3%ADs/#pt)   [**a.in**.da](https://forvo.com/word/ainda/#pt)
> *a.o*      [c**a.ó**.ti.co](https://forvo.com/word/ca%C3%B3tico/#pt)   [**a.on**.de](https://forvo.com/word/aonde/#pt)
> *a.u*      [s**a.ú**.de](https://forvo.com/word/sa%C3%BAde/#pt)
>
> *e.a*      [s**e.a**.ra](https://forvo.com/word/seara/#pt)   [á.r**e.a**](https://forvo.com/word/%C3%A1rea/#pt)   [l**e.ão**](https://forvo.com/word/le%C3%A3o/#pt)
> *e.e*      [com.pr**e.en**.der](https://forvo.com/word/compreender/#pt)   [can.d**e.ei**.ro](https://forvo.com/word/candeeiro/#pt)
> *e.i*       [d**e.í**s.mo](https://forvo.com/word/de%C3%ADsmo/#pt)   [d**e.i**.fi.car](https://forvo.com/word/deificar/#pt)
> *e.o*      [t**e.o**.ria](https://forvo.com/word/teoria/#pt)   [**e.ó**.li.co](https://forvo.com/word/e%C3%B3lico/#pt)   [al.v**é.o**.lo](https://forvo.com/word/alv%C3%A9olo/#pt)   [l**e.õe**s](https://forvo.com/word/le%C3%B5es/#pt)
> *e.u*      [r**e.u**.ni.ão](https://forvo.com/word/reuni%C3%A3o/#pt)   [con.**e.ú**.do](https://forvo.com/word/conte%C3%BAdo/#pt)
>
> *i.a*      [**í.a**.mos](https://forvo.com/word/%C3%ADamos/#pt)   [V**i.a**.na](https://forvo.com/word/viana/#pt)   [cr**i.an**.ça](https://forvo.com/word/crian%C3%A7a/#pt)   [p**i.ão**](https://forvo.com/word/pi%C3%A3o/#pt)   [cons.ci.ên.c**i.a**](https://forvo.com/word/consci%C3%AAncia/#pt)
> *i.e*      [v**i.e**.la](https://forvo.com/word/viela/#pt)   [fr**i.e**.za](https://forvo.com/word/frieza/#pt)   [cons.c**i.ên**.ci.a](https://forvo.com/word/consci%C3%AAncia/#pt)
> *i.i*       [ch**ei.i**.nho](https://forvo.com/word/cheiinho/#pt)   [f**i.í**ssi.mo](https://forvo.com/word/fri%C3%ADssimo/#pt)
> *i.o*      [e.t**í.o**.pe](https://forvo.com/word/et%C3%ADope/#pt)   [**i.o**.do](https://forvo.com/word/iodo/#pt)
> *i.u*      [m**i.ú**.do](https://forvo.com/word/mi%C3%BAdo/#pt)
>
> *o.a*      [b**o.a**.to](https://forvo.com/word/boato/#pt)   [v**o.an**.do](https://forvo.com/word/voando/#pt)   [J**o.ão**](https://forvo.com/word/jo%C3%A3o/#pt)
> *o.e*      [c**o.e**.lho](https://forvo.com/word/coelho/#pt)   [m**o.e**.la](https://forvo.com/word/moela/#pt)   [d**o.en**.ça](https://forvo.com/word/doen%C3%A7a/#pt)   [al.go.d**o.ei**.ro](https://forvo.com/word/algodoeiro/#pt)
> *o.i*       [m**o.i**.nho](https://forvo.com/word/moinho/#pt)
> *o.o*      [en.j**o.o**](https://forvo.com/word/enjoo/#pt)   [z**o.ó**.lo.go](https://forvo.com/word/zo%C3%B3logo/#pt)   [c**o.o**.pe.ra.ção](https://forvo.com/word/coopera%C3%A7%C3%A3o/#pt)
> *o.u*      c**o.u**.ti.li.za.ção      not in any dictionary; has been used [here](https://dre.pt/web/guest/home/-/dre/116982501/details/2/maximized?serie=II&jp=true&parte_filter=36&day=2018-11-15&date=2018-11-01&dreId=116968871)
>
> *u.a*      [tá.b**u.a**](https://forvo.com/word/t%C3%A1bua/#pt)   [l**u.a**](https://forvo.com/word/lua/#pt)   [s**u.a**.ve](https://forvo.com/word/suave/#pt)   [L**u.an**.da](https://forvo.com/word/luanda/#pt)   [s**u.ão**](https://forvo.com/word/su%C3%A3o/#pt)
> *u.e*      [d**u.e**.lo](https://forvo.com/word/duelo/#pt)   [d**u.en**.de](https://forvo.com/word/duende/#pt)   [c**u.ei**.ro](https://forvo.com/word/cueiro/#pt)
> *u.i*       [s**u.í**.no](https://forvo.com/word/su%C3%ADno/#pt)   [r**u.i**.do.so](https://forvo.com/word/ruidoso/#pt)
> *u.o*      [d**u.o**.dé.ci.mo](https://forvo.com/word/duod%C3%A9cimo/#pt)   [ár.d**u.o**](https://forvo.com/word/%C3%A1rduo/#pt)   [re.c**u.o**](https://forvo.com/word/recuo/#pt)
> *u.u*      [d**u.un**.vi.ra.to](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/duunvirato)   (no audio, phonetic transcription only)

### How can you tell whether two vowel letters make a diphthong or a hiatus?

You can in most cases when the main stress is there. Compare *pais* and *país*: the accented *í* tells you that it is a hiatus, *p**a.í**s*, and that the *i* is the stressed vowel, whereas in *pais*, *ai* is a diphthong. The same with *s**aú**da, r**uí**do*, etc.: the two adjacent vowels make a hiatus, and accent shows the stressed vowel; similar sequences with no accent, like *c**au**da*, *c**ui**do*, have diphthongs.

Exception. No accent is used if the second vowel is followed by *l, m, n, r*, or *z*, and makes a syllable with it; that vowel is still stressed and it is a hiatus though: *p**a.u**l*, *C**o.im**.bra*, ***a.in**.da*, *r**u.i**r*, *j**u.i**z*. Note that these consonants must belong to the same syllable with the preceding vowel: *R**a.u**l* (hiatus), but *P**au**.lo* (diphthong), because in *Paulo* the *l* forms a syllable with the following *o*, not the preceding *u*. No accent is used either if the second vowel is followed by *nh*: *r**a.i**.nha*.

Another exception. So far we’ve relied on stressed diphthongs not requiring accents. But they do in the third-to-last syllable: *te.ra.p**êu**.ti.co*. How can we tell it is not *te.ra.p**ê.u**.ti.co*. Well, I don’t know this is a general rule, but the only hiatuses that I know of that are accented in the first vowel are *é.o* (*al.v**é.o**.lo*), *í.a* (*tr**í.a**.da*, *Lu.s**í.a**das*) and *í.o* (*va.r**í.o**.la*, *pe.r**í.o**.do*, *m**í.o**.pe*), and there is no diphthong *eo*, *ia* or *io* (remember, oral diphthongs are vowel + *i*/*u*, or follow the pattern *qu*/*gu* + vowel). So it is safe to assume that anything like *êu* is a diphthong. We also put an accent on diphthongs *éi, éu* and *ói* at the end of a word (including monosyllables): *pa.p**éi**s*, *cha.p**éu***, *v**éu***, *s**ói**s*, *cons.tr**ói***, so that we know the accented vowel is open, not closed. Again, this does not fit the pattern *é.o* or *í.o*.

**The real problem** is in unstressed syllables. For instance, it is [*c**ui**.da.do*](https://forvo.com/word/cuidado/#pt), but [*r**u.i**.do.so*](https://forvo.com/word/ruidoso/#pt); we cannot, as before, put an accent on the *i* of the hiatus, because it is unstressed; the stressed syllable is *do*. Same with [*r**ei**.fi.car*](https://forvo.com/word/reificar/#pt) and [*d**e.i**.fi.car*](https://forvo.com/search/deificar/pt/); [*r**eu**mático*](https://forvo.com/word/reum%C3%A1tico/#pt) and [*r**e.u**ni.do*](https://forvo.com/word/reunido/#pt). So any pair vowel + *i*/*u* in an unstressed position could in theory be a diphthong or a hiatus. If you do not know, the only way is to look up a dictionary that shows syllable separation, like [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/ruidoso) , [Michaelis](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/ruidoso/)  (Brazilian standard), [Priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/ruidoso) (you can select Brazilian or European standard) or [Infopédia (European standard)](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/ruidoso).

Comment: Good answer! The problem with hiatuses is pretty complex, as you said, since hiatuses can become diphthongs, but something that I don't know is how many words can be both, without the hiatus becoming a diphthong I mean? For example, the word “saudade” has basically two pronunciations, one with a hiatus (/sa-u/) or with a diphthong (/sau/). It is just a comment, but I think interesting the word “saudade”. Congrats.

Comment: @Schilive, I wouldn't know how many of those there are. In Portugal quite a lot a people, most, I reckon, pronounce *io* in words like *tio* and *rio* as a diphthong!

Comment: it was more like a question to the air. Where I live in Brazil, “tio” and “rio” have a hiatus, but it becomes a diphthong in fast speech, not needing to be that fast.

Comment: @Schilive, I had some notion of those pronunciations of *saudade*. I actually wanted to use a word of that family, with the hiatus pronuntiation, for a contrast like *s**a.u**.do.so* versus *c**au**.te.loso* to ilustrate that an unstressed *au* can be hiatus or diphthong, and was quite upset to find out that nearly all dictionaries give the diphthong pronunciation only. Aulete is the exception.

Comment: @Schilive, whereas I fill the hiatus with the semivowel [j], /tijw/, creating a triphthong. Once comparing my *tio* with Portugese coleages that do the diphtong, and a Carioca, I though that the Carioca did a hiatus, but she found her pronunciation like my triphthong. I guess /ti.u/ and /tijw/ are a lot closer to each other than either is to /tiw/.

Comment: as far as I know, which ain't much, the pronunciation with the hiatus (“saüdade” in old-writing) is considered old — Camões used it, for example —, so it's understandable. Aulete is great for older stuff. I believe that with that triphthong only happens consciously, so it doesn' count here. About the closeness, in Brazilian Portuguese it is common for “ti” to become “tchi”, which makes the distinction harder; also adding that it also happens to omit the “i” in informal speech when “t” is “tch”.

Answer (score 2):

If you really just want the list of diphthongs, then the Wikipedia article on *ditongos* shows a list of the existing diphthongs: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ditongo
They're not organized, but they're there.

But you should consider the points raised by Jacinto and Schilive in the comments to your question.

---

If what you are looking for is to split words into syllables occasionally, the [Priberam online dictionary](https://dicionario.priberam.org/) splits the words into their syllables.

See e.g. Priberam splitting "bolacha" into its 3 syllables:

> - bo·la·cha
>
> "bolacha", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha], 2008-2020, https://dicionario.priberam.org/bolacha [consultado em 14-12-2020].

---

If what you want is an exhaustive list of diphthongs, a quick internet search will provide you with many results even if you search in English, such as https://www.learningportuguese.co.uk/guide/pronunciation/diphthongs

Wikipedia has plenty of information on this, both in Portuguese (more specific and with sillabary examples) and in English (more technical, with IPA notations and few examples).

---

Note that there are also some triphtongs (*tritongos*), even if they are rare: U·ru·g**uai**, q**uai**s·quer, etc.
The Wikipedia article on [triphthong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triphthong) mentions portuguese examples.

Comment: I am sorry, but what about the hiatuses? If I didn't see it, I'm sorry.

Comment: I don't know much about hiatuses, other than what a quick search teaches. Sorry, I'm not sure what you are looking for in that regard, or how I could help. You'll need more complete help from someone else. :)

Comment: Faz-me uma certa espécie estes gajos que acham que a pergunta merece uma resposta mas não um voto.